# What is this coin? Figure in rose. Rev: Mansion

Tags: identification, numismatics

[image][image]
Looks old can only make out one word (my death )
Other than that no idea.

Comment: A better-focused picture of the reverse would certainly help.

Comment: Please add as much information as you can, including dimensions, weight, where you acquired the coin, etc.

Comment: It looks very much like a Tudor rose (around the female figure), but it is not similar to tudor-era english coins.

Comment: Based on the edge, I've got a feeling it may be a fantasy coin.

Comment: "My death" is two words, which prompts me to ask whether you are translating from another language, and if so from which?

Comment: The full phrase might read "After my death I will let fall a shower of roses", which would make the figure in the middle Saint Therese. That could mean the house is Les Buissonnets, but it doesn't look much like it…

Comment: In any case from the inscription I think it's a catholic devotional medal for Saint Thérèse of Lisieux.